# Python: How to create a Minmax function that loops over every single column in a df?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to make a Minmax function for my `df`, where the function must take each and every column of the `df` individually and process it.

**What I have done:**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing


data = pd.DataFrame({ 'col1' : ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3'],
        'col2' : ['5', '8', '7', '12', '2', '1', '3', '15', '4'],
        'col3' : ['6', '8', '8', '10', '5', '1', '0', '6', '3'],
        'col4' : ['7', '7', '7', '0', '20', '12', '5', '5', '1']
        }, dtype='int32')

def minmax(column):
    float_array = data[column].values.astype(float).reshape(-1,1)
    min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    scaled_array = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(float_array)


for data.column in data.columns[1:]:
    minmax(data.column)
```

When I run this, I get no output. So when I changed the `minmax(data.column)` in the `for` loop to `print(minmax(data.column))`, it shows the following output:

```
for data.column in data.columns[1:]:
    print(minmax(data.column))
None
None
None
```

Can someone please explain what is the mistake I am doing here?

Thanks

**Edit 1:**

I would like to output to be in such a format that I can feed it into another function that does `OneClassSVM` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 problems - missing `return` in function and in loop use new variable, e.g. `c` for iterate over the members of columns names:

```
def minmax(column):
    float_array = data[column].values.astype(float).reshape(-1,1)
    min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    scaled_array = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(float_array)
    return scaled_array

for c in data.columns[1:]:
    arr = minmax(c)
    print (arr)
```

---

```
for c in data.columns[1:]:
    arr1 = data[c].values.astype(float).reshape(-1,1)
    #array for next processing
    print (arr1)
```

Comment: Hey, @jezrael, thanks for the help. One question: When I execute the print command, a variable named c of type string and size 1 is being formed. Is there a way I can change this to into such a format so that I can then send it as an input to a different function that shall do OneclassSVM on it?

Comment: @Bibliophile20 - hmmm, machine learning is not easy for me, but in my opinion you can use similar approach like in your function - if need `2d` array.

Comment: @Bibliophile20 - But is possible  I am wrong, because it depends what you need do exactly.